# Can't drop element after the drag

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, draggable

I'm new in JS and trying to make simple interface with pure JS, where User can dynamically add elements and move them around.
I found solutions for create elements and drag'n'drop elements, that perfectly works separatly. But when I tried to unite them, drop function stop working...

What am I doing wrong?

Template:

```
    <head>
        <title>Int Demo</title>
        <script src='js/script.js'></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            .wrapper {width: 300px; height: 200px; background: #A3A1A1;}
            .textblock {cursor: pointer; background: red;}
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="button" id="button">Add Textbox</div>
        <div class="wrapper" id="wrapper"></div>
    </body>

</html>
```

My JS file:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { init(); }, false);

function init() {
    button = document.getElementById('button');
    wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');

    button.addEventListener('click', btnClick, false);
    wrapper.ondblclick  = catchIt;
}

//add element

function btnClick() {
    wrapper.innerHTML += '<p class="draggable textblock">Text Here!</p>';
    sessionStorage.inputBoxes = wrapper;
    console.log(sessionStorage);
}

// Activate Drag'n'Drop

document.onmousedown = function(e) {

  var dragElement = e.target;

  if (!dragElement.classList.contains('draggable')) return;

  var coords, shiftX, shiftY;

  startDrag(e.clientX, e.clientY);

  document.onmousemove = function(e) {
    moveAt(e.clientX, e.clientY);
  };

  dragElement.onmouseup = function() {
    finishDrag();
  };

  function startDrag(clientX, clientY) {

    shiftX = clientX - dragElement.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    shiftY = clientY - dragElement.getBoundingClientRect().top;

    dragElement.style.position = 'fixed';

    document.body.appendChild(dragElement);

    moveAt(clientX, clientY);
  };

  function finishDrag() {
    dragElement.style.top = parseInt(dragElement.style.top) + pageYOffset + 'px';
    dragElement.style.position = 'absolute';

    document.onmousemove = null;
    dragElement.onmouseup = null;
  }

  function moveAt(clientX, clientY) {
    var newX = clientX - shiftX;
    var newY = clientY - shiftY;

    // bottom offset
    var newBottom = newY + dragElement.offsetHeight;

    if (newBottom > document.documentElement.clientHeight) {

      var docBottom = document.documentElement.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;

      var scrollY = Math.min(docBottom - newBottom, 10);


      if (scrollY < 0) scrollY = 0;

      window.scrollBy(0, scrollY);

      newY = Math.min(newY, document.documentElement.clientHeight - dragElement.offsetHeight);
    }


    // top offset
    if (newY < 0) {
      var scrollY = Math.min(-newY, 10);
      if (scrollY < 0) scrollY = 0;

      window.scrollBy(0, -scrollY);
      newY = Math.max(newY, 0);
    }

    if (newX < 0) newX = 0;
    if (newX > document.documentElement.clientWidth - dragElement.offsetHeight) {
      newX = document.documentElement.clientWidth - dragElement.offsetHeight;
    }

    dragElement.style.left = newX + 'px';
    dragElement.style.top = newY + 'px';
  }

  return false;
}
```

Comment: Just wondering, have you looked into html5 drag n drop specifications? They're native since html5 and it might be simpler if those'd be appropriate for what you're trying to make.

Comment: @Shilly I tried to use native drag'n'drop functionality, but had a lot of problems with it in my interfaces. Maybe, I does spmething weong, but I desided to go back to JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed

```
dragElement.onmouseup = function() {
    finishDrag();
};
```

into

```
document.onmouseup = function() {
    finishDrag();
};
```

and it started working for me. This does mean that the end user will have to keep the mouse button pressed down to continue dragging and that the element will be placed immediately on mouse button up. But I'm assuming that this is the desired functionality, or do you want the drop to happen only on a second mouse click?

Comment: No, you made it as I expect it work)) Thank you)) All works fine now.